# Representation of logarithms in terms of the zeta-$\zeta(n)$ function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, riemann-zeta

I've been looking for representations of logarithms in terms of the zeta function. So for $\ln(2)$ we have this and more here

\begin{align*}
 \ln(2)=&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k+1)}{2^{k+1}}\\
 \ln(2)=&1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2 n)}{2^{2 n-1}(2 n+1)}\\
\end{align*}

and for $\ln(3)$ I've found

\begin{align*}
\ln(3)=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2k+1)}{3^{2k+1}}
\end{align*}

but for other logarithms,$\ln(4)$, $\ln(5)$ etc.., I didn't find anything.

Could someone point directions or post here representations of logarithms in terms of $\zeta(n)$?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
After some refinement of the expression given bellow I was able to get this beauty:
$$\boxed{
\;\;\;\;
\ln (n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(k+1)}{n^{k+1}} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} m^{k}
\;\;\;\;}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the series ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.8.E7))
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta\left(k\right)}{k}z^{k}=-\gamma z+\ln\Gamma\left
(1-z\right)
\end{equation} 
valid for $\left|z\right|<1$ and the multiplication formula for the gamma function ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E7))
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=(2\pi)^{(n-1)/2}n^{-1/2}
\end{align}
Taking the logarithm and reversing the order of summation of the later expression gives
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{p=1}^{n-1}\ln\Gamma\left(1-\frac{p}{n}\right)=(n-1)\ln(2\pi)-\ln n
\end{equation} 
From these results, it comes
\begin{equation}
\ln n=(n-1)\left(\ln(2\pi)-\gamma  \right)-2\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(k)}{kn^k}\sum_{p=1}^{n-1}p^k
\end{equation}
If we want to remove the $\ln(2\pi)-\gamma$ term, we can use the expression for $n=2$:
\begin{equation}
\ln 2=\ln(2\pi)-\gamma  -2\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(k)}{k2^k}
\end{equation} 
and the classical expansion:
\begin{equation}
\ln(2)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{2^{k}}
\end{equation} 
to deduce
\begin{align}
\ln(2\pi)-\gamma& =\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{2^{k}}+2\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(k)}{k2^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{2^{k}}\left( 1+\frac{2}{k} \right)
\end{align} 
and thus
\begin{equation}
\ln n=(n-1)\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(k)}{2^{k}}\left( 1+\frac{2}{k} \right)-2\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\zeta(k)}{kn^k}\sum_{p=1}^{n-1}p^k
\end{equation}

Comment: Alternatively from $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta\left(k\right)}{k}z^{k}=-\gamma z+\ln\Gamma\left(1-z\right)
$ use $\log\Gamma(1+1/n) = -\log n +\log \Gamma(1/n)$ which gives $-\log n+\gamma $ taking $n=2$ and the series for $\log 2$ gives a series for $\gamma$ thus $\log n$

Answer (score 1):

Note that, $ln(4) = 2ln(2)$. Since you have the representation for $ln(2)$, you can obtain one for $ln(4)$. So in general, for $ln(2^k)$ as well, where $k=1,2,3,4...$.

Similarly you can find the representation for any integer $n$ of the form $n={2^a}{3^b}$, where $a,b$ are positive integers